# Sort contacts by contact name

Tags: android, sorting, android-contacts

I want to sort contacts when they are fetched and I give the statement an order by contact name but nothing works.

**This is my codes**

```
public static TreeMap<String, String> getContactsMobileNumbersAndNames(Context context) {
    TreeMap<String, String> result = new TreeMap<>();
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    int phoneType = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    if (phoneType == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        result.put(phoneNo, name);
                    }
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }
    }
    cur.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Check this out [link](http://androhub.com/android-read-contacts-using-content-provider/).

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap is the map that is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys as default. You tried to sort your contacts according to phone numbers. Thus, if want to work your code, you need to change this line:

```
result.put(phoneNo, name);
```

with this line:

```
result.put(name, phoneNo);
```

Also, you can get the sorted contacts without using TreeMap as follows:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


public void retrieveContactList() {

    Cursor phones = null;

    try {
        phones = activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String _number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            String _name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
            contact.put("NUMBER", _number);
            contact.put("NAME", _name);
            contactList.add(contact);
        }

        phones.close();

    } catch ( Exception e ) {}

    finally {
        if(phones != null){
            phones.close();
        }
    }
}

public void printContacts() {

    for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
        Log.v(contactList.get(i).get("NAME"), contactList.get(i).get("NUMBER"));
    }
}
```

However, if you insist to use a map, there is no need to get contacts in sorted order. Put them in HashMap (key is number and value is name) in your getter method and then, while reading the keys and values, transfer all the content from HashMap to TreeMap:

```
treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
```

Now you can print the content in sorted order.

Comment: I cannot put to the map by contact name because of duplicate contacts. It replaces the other one.

Comment: You need to use ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> as data structure to store contacts. I edited my answer, could you please check it out?